# Is GDPR-compliant Structured Streaming possible in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

We want to use Spark Structured Streaming to process data, which needs to be deleted after a certain amount of time to be GDPR-compliant. In our program, we have two input streaming dataframes, which are joined in a stream-stream join. The resulting streaming dataframe is then written to an output file.

To be GDPR-compliant, we need the data in both input streams as well as in the output stream to be deleted after a certain amount of time. Is it possible to delete data which exceeds a certain time stamp inside Spark Streaming Dataframes?

We have already looked into the Watermarking in Spark, which stops new data with a timestamp older than the watermark from being written into the output stream. However, data with a timestamp older than the watermark which is already present in either input or output streams is not being deleted. Is there a way to achieve this?

For example, for Apache Flink I have found the time-to-live (TTL) feature which enables application state cleanup: https://flink.apache.org/2019/05/19/state-ttl.html
Is there something similar for Spark?

Comment: I doubt it, but may be someone will surprise me.

Comment: Title is not correct, GDPR is more than this.

Comment: What about the already written output?

Comment: We are already taking care of deleting the already written output, the current question just regards the data inside the Spark Streaming Dataframes.

Comment: Interesting to say the least. How are you doing that?

Comment: You'd have to use some variant of mapGroupsWithState and explicitly delete data older then X in your state

Comment: As an Architect I look for simplicity. Here you seem to want to solve the same problem twice. I would suggest when persisting to embellish the already existing logic there - if that satisfies the GDPR aspects. But you tell too little in the question.

Comment: Nice flink feature